# How can I improve the performance of the Oracle CX connector?

Tags: python, oracle, networking

Oracle is a fast database, but CX Oracle appears extraordinarily slow, and I have no idea why.  For simple queries, CX Oracle seems to be the bottleneck.

I have a table that is a 2000x5 matrix of integers.  And I have a 500us roundtrip latency to my database.

```
>>> %timeit cx_con.ping()
504 µs ± 7.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

`cursor.execute` is unexpectedly slow in the most simple case. It's nearly twice as slow.

```
In [257]: %time cursor.execute("select count(*) from matrix_table"); res = cursor.fetchall()
CPU times: user 424 µs, sys: 41 µs, total: 465 µs
Wall time: 932 µs
```

If I'm reading this correctly, we spend half of that time in the network (467us walltime-totalcpu).  Which is fine, but what on earth is happening for the rest of the the 465us? When I took a look in 'v$sql', the query takes about 65us.  Which leaves 400us to marshal a single integer.  Assuming that Oracle has a fairly efficient wire protocol, that should take nanoseconds.

What worries me is that the time spent (presumably) marshalling data, increases very quickly.

```
In [25]: %time cursor.execute("select id,customer_id from matrix_table"); print(len(cursor.fetchmany()))
100
CPU times: user 552 µs, sys: 50 µs, total: 602 µs
Wall time: 1.04 ms

In [26]: cursor = cx_oracle.cursor()

In [27]: cursor.arraysize = 500

In [28]: cursor.prefetchrows = 500

In [29]: %time cursor.execute("select id,customer_id from matrix_table"); print(len(cursor.fetchmany()))
500
CPU times: user 947 µs, sys: 86 µs, total: 1.03 ms
Wall time: 1.89 ms

In [30]: cursor = cx_oracle.cursor()

In [31]: cursor.arraysize = 1000

In [32]: cursor.prefetchrows = 1000

In [33]: %time cursor.execute("select id,customer_id from matrix_table"); print(len(cursor.fetchmany()))
1000
CPU times: user 2.27 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 2.27 ms
Wall time: 2.73 ms
```

I know Python isn't the fastest language, but spending nearly 2 milliseconds marshalling 2000 integers in a binary format is absurdly slow.  As you can see, each 500 rows, seems to roughly add 800us to the processing time.

I've left the all the settings like the Oracle Session Data unit unchanged. I've run the connector with `strace`, and I see an expected number of syscalls.

Comment: _"Assuming that Oracle has a fairly efficient wire protocol,"_   Oracle has no wire protocol at all.  In fact it has no real networking capability of its own.  In the standard OSI network stack, Oracle Net lives at the "session" layer.  From there it relies on the OS for the lower layers - Transport, Network, Data Link, and Physical.

Comment: I thought anything above the transport layer is 'wire' protocol.  That is, if it's read from a socket, it's a wire protocol. It's a pretty vague term. Are you saying that Oracle implements its own networking stack, like its own networking driver?

Comment: From what I can find, the Transparent Network Substrate Protocol, is just a little adapter over sockets, pipes, and SDP (which is a dead format).  What I found here https://web.archive.org/web/20170222101953/http://www.thesprawl.org/research/oracle-tns-protocol/, it's little more than a 8byte header on the wire protocol.

Comment: well, you just went beyond my knowledge of networking.  What I know is that in the OSI model, Oracle's tns is at the session level.  See Fig. 4-1 and 4-2 in the Network Services Administrator's Guide - https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/netag/understanding-communication-layers.html#GUID-CC082D31-FA89-4905-99DA-B507FB1B52F7.  From the Transport Layer down, it's out of Oracle's hands.

Comment: did you look at the session stats in the db to see how much time is spent on the net? v$sess_stats, sqlnet data to client? it gives you a better idea than just conn.ping